# How can I install Windows from my current Windows OS

Tags: windows-10

I made a new partition and I want to install Windows 10 on it.

I have the ISO file.

Can I install Windows on the new partition, from within my current working Windows?
(No USB / DVD)

Will it work if I unpack and install regularly?

Comment: @LPChip - I already did

Comment: @Ramhound Gotcha. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

> Can I install Windows on the new partition, from within my current
>   working Windows?

It is not possible to install Windows on the new partition, from within Windows, if you attempt to do that you will only modify the installation you currently have running.

> Will it work if I unpack and install regularly?

This will not work.  Simply extracting the compress files contained within the ISO will NOT install Windows on the partition in question.

> I made a new partition and I want to install Windows 10 on it.

In order to install Windows on this new partition, you will need to create bootable installation disk, you will NOT be able to accomplish it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to install Windows 10 on a new partition by adapting a method used to create a dual-boot configuration based on a vhdx file.

**Warning:** You will be playing with the boot manager, so you should be ready to restore your machine from backup if anything goes wrong.

**Note:** If your ISO image is ESD-based, use *install.esd* instead of *install.wim* when following the instructions.

I assume your new, empty, NTFS-formatted partition is available under driver letter W:

1. Double click the ISO file to mount it as a virtual DVD drive. Note the drive letter that was assigned to it. Let's assume it is letter E:
2. Your ISO image can contain multiple Windows editions. To know which image you want to use, list the editions using the following command:

   ```
   dism /Get-WimInfo /wimFile:E:\Sources\install.wim
   ```
3. Note the index number of the edition you want to install
4. Apply the Windows image to your new partition using the index number you found:

   ```
   dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:E:\Sources\install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:W:\
   ```
5. Add your new installation to the boot menu as the default one:

   ```
   bcdboot W:\Windows
   ```
6. Reboot the machine to finalize the Windows installation